# Should Arqade migrate questions about online board games here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Over on the video game site Arqade [a discussion about an online card game platform called OCTGN](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/what-is-octgn-and-why-are-we-providing-tech-support-for-it) is taking place. The suggestion there is that since this is an implementation of a way to play (physical) card games, such questions would be better off being migrated here. If that was the consensus, we would start to receive all such questions asked over there.

Obviously, this is a bit of a gray area between the two sites. So far, we have been allowing most questions about [online](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) implementations.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

**No**, we are not a technical support site. These type of questions are a better fit for Superuser.SE

The relevant information was provided by the head support lead for the software, keldon52

> The purpose of this software isn't for a specific card game, or board game, it supports many games. The problem is, we aren't forwarding people here for questions on how to play rummy, we're forwarding people here for problems with the software, or port forwarding, or how to log into the client. Other ones would be "How do I make a game, how do I scroll around the board, how do I tap a card, shuffle a deck, invite 4 players and setup some complicated match".

These technical questions are likely not a good fit for the site.

Comment: Although it's not a perfect parallel, BoardGameGeek.com has been increasingly sending discussion about even computer implementations of board games to the sister site VideoGameGeek.com.